# How to remove first and last double Quotes from a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am getting this as response from a Ajax JSONP Call

```
"{"userType":"New","UUID":"787878"} "
```

How can I remove the first `"` and last `"` double quotes?

So that the response looks like

```
{"userType":"New","UUID":"787878"}
```

Comment: fix the service that provides the result to return valid json (*which service is that btw?*)

Comment: How are you concluding that the quotes are there? If the service is returning the quotes, your jsonp request would immediately fail and there's nothing you can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify does not add double quotes around the object, it turns it into a string. If you are seeing extra double quotes, it's just due to whatever is displaying it, they aren't really there.

Comment: @PreethiJain if you think this isn't the case, provide a reproducible test case.